# Is it normal to let another person lead the writing of a project that you performed most of the analysis?

Tags: publications, authorship, collaboration

I am a final year Ph.D. collaborating with people in my lab (Biomedical) and spent more than a year on this side project which is not part of my thesis research. My results combined with some calculations (which I also performed a bit) from a colleague (research associate) can make up a story and we decided to write the manuscript. In the beginning, we agree that I can lead the manuscript and she can co-lead to help with writing.
But now, she wants something out of the project as soon as possible and feels that this manuscript may add on too much workload on me in my final year. And she would like to bring up a discussion with our supervisor that due to timing issues, she wants to lead the manuscript. It's true that she can speed up the processes as I will be busy writing other manuscripts and my thesis. The whole project does need a published paper now so that subsequential works can rely on that.
However, I feel a bit uncomfortable about letting someone else lead a manuscript (I will be a coauthor for sure) when I performed most part of the analysis. I don't mind having more workload on my shoulders but I can be slow with many parallel projects. My always states that it's a decision between me and the colleague. So my question is that：

（1）is timing a strong reason to let others take the lead in a manuscript, given that I really want to lead the writing of my own work?

（2）Shall I let my colleague lead the manuscript and take the first author in favor of time? Does the authorship ranking mean a lot? I only had one paper published for now.

(3) If I want to make the conversation, how shall I start?

Comment: Does this also mean that you would have been the first author on this manuscript, but if this colleague  writes it up that they will be first author?

Comment: Yes, whoever writes the manuscript will be the first author. But I feel like I can be the co-first if my colleague lead the writing

Comment: Why do you think that the act of actually writing down the results is so important in setting the first author. Authorship is more than about writing. Let the best writer be the writer and choose author order based on the research (intellectual) contribution. After all, you've tagged this collaboration, not competition.

Comment: I guess that the rule most people in my field follow.  It's also how people in my lad determine the author rankings.

Comment: I suggest that you work out author order before anyone writes anything and, only, then decide who is best to write it up and how the others will contribute to that - revisions and such. My preference would be to let the best writer do the writing, though they need the time for it. But the writing isn't the main intellectual contribution. And, if you are in a situation where everyone contributes equally, then use something like alphabetical order or a clear statement in an acknowledgements paragraph.

Comment: That's a really good suggestion. It's just I am a student and may not have the "big picture".  It's true that my colleague is a more experienced writer.  But I feel you can't just let the best writer always be the writer and not give chances to inexperienced students to try due to urgency.

Comment: Part of my reasoning is that there is (a lot of) value in having the best paper. Someone with a lot of writing experience is better able to produce that, other things being equal. I'm not putting value on being quick here, but only in being clear. But your point about getting experience is a good one.

Comment: @shukurra If it was your *only* paper I think it would certainly make sense both for your supervisor and for your own training that you insist to write all parts of a manuscript to get the experience. But you've described this as a bit of a "side project" where, even though you've led the effort, you have other efforts going on where you are doing more of the writing. In that context, it'd be okay to get help with the writing, I just don't think you should sacrifice earned authorship order for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'll note that doing it "quickly" serves her interests, but maybe not yours especially if she can take over first authorship. She would need to justify that. If she wants to do a lot of the writing, but leave you as first author then that issue goes away and is easier to justify the "speedy" request. Don't let yourself get abused here. The advice of @BryanKrause is good advice.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a strategic mistake to give up first authorship on a project if you've done most of the work on the experimental side of things just to have someone else write the text. When people browse through your CV in your field, **they will likely assume that the author listed first did the work**, and that the last author is the primary senior person supervising the work. Any other middle author presumably had *some* contribution, but it's not clear how much.

It doesn't seem fair to me for someone to take over a first authorship position just by writing in order to get the paper out quicker. The balance might shift a bit if the overall time you put in to this point is not extensive (i.e., collecting data from a repository, running calculations, etc, is all important work, but may be marginal relative to doing a year of bench experiments). I think ultimately this is something you will need to weigh for yourself, as well as weigh against opportunity costs - if you're going to be writing this paper, does that prevent you from doing something else that's more valuable to you than having this first author paper?

On the other hand, I think it's perfectly normal especially in the biomedical area that the person who does the research and is listed as **first author need not necessarily be the person who writes up the first draft of all of the paper**. You definitely want to get some writing experience as a student, but it sounds like you're already doing your own writing, and this is just an additional project for you. You have to decide for yourself how much value you put on the additional writing experience (and mentorship that comes with revising your writing in consultation with your coauthors).

A reasonable middle ground you could propose is that you keep first authorship and draft the "meat" (methods, results) of the paper while your colleague helps with the "framing" (introduction, discussion). However, if your colleague is just trying to grab a first author paper for themselves and not acting in your best interests, this arrangement would not be suitable. Someone more senior might have a better "big picture" view of the field that is helpful in writing the introduction and discussion sections.

When discussing authorship issues with colleagues, I think it's important that you be prepared to defend your own interests - in your case, it seems those interests are 1) a first author paper is valuable, and 2) you feel it is important (perhaps especially as learning experience) to write your own work. Any negotiation should start there, and you should be careful to consider others priorities without sacrificing your own. If *time* is really the main concern, then maybe you are willing to sacrifice (2) but not (1).

Comment: Note that "time spent" isn't the proper measure of academic contribution.

Comment: @Buffy No, certainly not, but in most things biomedicine it's a pretty good proxy of who is the first author on a paper. It would definitely be unfair treatment to a student who spent two years doing experiments to say "well, us senior people decided the direction and trained you how to do the experiments and told you to do an ANOVA, so we made all the intellectual contribution and you can be a middle author, we'll be first and last."

Comment: Hmmm, there is "time" and there is "productive activity" which may take time. But it is possible to spend a lot of time fruitlessly, probably even in biomedical research.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. More information: My colleague and I are both early career researchers. I am a final year Ph.D. and she is a postdoc. My analysis part is not bench experiments but also some sort of modeling analysis which will be the basis of all subsequential projects.  I initiated the wrapping up calculations at the beginning but she took over that part because it's the same framework that she will be using in the subsequential projects.  My point is that given that I will be writing most of the methods and results, why hurt just letting me write the whole thing?

Comment: Now you are surprising me and I upvoted. But you seem to be describing a situation in which a person makes no intellectual contribution at all and simply works at the close direction of others. I hope it isn't like that.

Comment: @Buffy Sure, though I'd be careful about what is considered "fruitless" in biology as anywhere else, as ruling out things that don't work is fruitful and can be quite an important intellectual contribution. My point was that the scope for the effort towards "collecting data" varies incredibly in biomedical studies, and can span designing entire (pre)clinical trials to pulling some entries from an existing database. The former involves a lot of intellectual contribution "along the way" even if ultimately both approaches primarily contribute a table of data to analyze.

Comment: @Buffy From the perspective of the students it is not like that; from the perspective of some supervisors it might be.

Comment: More details: I have a good relationship with my colleague and I don't want to ruin it.  She came to all the discussions and made really good suggestions and comments while I was performing the analysis. So definitely intellectual contributions.  And I will use her calculations to make a whole story for sure.

Comment: Does that explain the fact(?) that in some fields people just assume that the "last author" (the advisor or PI) _really_ did all the work and all the other "authors" just ride along? I've read that in some questions on this site, and it has always seemed foreign to me, but this would explain it (if true).

Comment: @shukurra If it's primarily your project, you should probably be first author, whatever additional effort from you that means. "She came to all the discussions and made really good suggestions and comments while I was performing the analysis. So definitely intellectual contributions. And I will use her calculations to make a whole story for sure." - these all seem to be great marks of coauthorship, not first authorship.

Comment: I fully concur with your most recent comment.

Comment: In my case, our supervisor will be the last author since she wrote the proposal get the funding, and brought the whole plan. I am not quite sure what you want to comment here.

Comment: @Buffy I think it's almost always wrong to assume the last author "really did all the work", but often much more fair to characterize it as "work done in Prof Lastauthor's lab" as much as "work done by Firstauthor", when Firstauthor is a trainee.

Comment: @shukurra Sorry, I think Buffy and I have drifted off on a bit of a tangent. My main messages to you are 1) if it's your project, you should be the first author. 2) If to be first author you need to write the whole paper, then that's what you should do, even if it takes longer. 3) It's totally fine for a coauthor to write parts of the manuscript, no matter where they are in the author order, but of course it's up to that coauthor to agree to do that work while being whatever order author they are.

Comment: I agree with that. So this authorship issue bothered me a bit as a Ph.D. student. It's just it is so hard for me to make the conversation, as I feel that my supervisor always holds the big picture and prefers to do whatever benefits the whole projects.

Comment: The dividing up of the writing, with you writing methods and results (which tend to be easier and more straightforward to write in my opinion) is good advice.

Comment: I don’t see what benefit you would get for writing up the whole thing as long as you are first author either way. Writing the intro and conclusion doesn’t pass the cost-benefit test here…

Comment: @Dawn From the perspective of OP being a graduate student, I could see making a case that an important part of their graduate research experience should be writing up the entirety of a publishable paper, intro and discussion included. But, although I've suggested that as a middle ground they can propose, I doubt their colleague will go along because I think she just wants to snag an easy first author paper by offering to write a paper for a graduate student.

Answer (score 0):

I think some crucial pieces of the story are missing here. As far as I understand, the topic starter collected the results, and his colleague analyzed them.

1. Who actually conceptualized the study and designed the experiments? Was it you? Was it your colleague? If it was one of you two - that person is a likely genuine first author. If the third party was involved, it is reasonable to engage this person now and get their input on the final authorship.
2. How (non)trivial were the experiments vs. analysis? Some experiments are routine procedures usually done by assistants, and others are out-of-this-world procedures. Vice versa, some analysis is just numbers pushed through the standard pipeline, and others are unique.
3. You should ask yourself one practical question before disputing the authorship/writing: will you ever have time to finish the manuscript yourself? You said you are in a final year of a Ph.D. So, now you are busy, but it will not get better after the defense. Will you leave academia for the industry? Go for a postdoc in another group/university/country? Neither of these places will give you time to work on the past things. So you may never actually finish the paper. On the other hand, negotiating co-first authorship now and "moving on" with other projects/jobs may be the best strategy to see some outcome. Of course, no one but the topic starter can assess the situation here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! To answer the questions: (1) My part of work incorporates constructing a novel model to perform the analysis of some data. The whole idea was brought by my supervisor since she is the one who applied for funding and wrote the proposal. But the detailed plan and structure were designed by me.  (2) My methods and results can be a paper by its own but adding more calculations can make a better story. I also did the calculations at the beginning but my colleague took over it since she will be using the framework for her subsequential projects. (3) I plan to sty academi